# Why is 'Attach to Process' in Visual Studio 2012 to w3wp.exe so slow?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging a webapplication on IIS, attach to process to the w3wp.exe worker process, takes a good few minutes, loading a large number of dll files, ones ever few seconds.  The machine is running Windows 8 with 8 cores and 16GB ram, so not really a machine limitation.

It makes attaching to process such a painful procedure.

Just a sample from the output window:

```
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-audits.core'
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime\v4.0_2.1.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll'
```

Is it this slow for anyone else, if not, what can be done to improve performance?

Comment: You can make a whitelist of the symbols you really need.

Comment: Do you have any finding for this? How to get the attaching process sped up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is pretty old, but I think your issue is all the symbols being loaded that you don't actually need (but may want).

You can greatly reduce the number of symbols attempting to load by (un)setting a couple options:

```
Tools | Options | Debugging | General - check "Enable Just My Code"
Tools | Options | Debugging | Symbols - uncheck "Microsoft Symbol Servers"
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, the "Enable Just My Code" setting worked a charm!